# Inference from PCA (Using Python) on Oil Stock Returns

Tags: python, pca

I was interested in finding out if there are a few common factors that have been driving the returns in individual stocks in the U.S. Oil sector, sourcing the daily closing prices from Yahoo!. Below is the (fairly simple) Python code I used, with the final result (the graph) presented all the way down below showing the top 2 PCs (as they seem to explain most of the variance). Problem is I can't make heads or tails of the plot. Not sure what can be inferred at all from this! Anyone willing to take a stab and/or point out the ugliness in my implementation? :-)

Sincerely.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statistics as st
%matplotlib inline

symbols=['XOM','CVX','SLB','PXD','EOG','OXY','HAL','KMI','SE','PSX','VLO','COP','APC','TSO','WMB','BHI','APA','COG','DVN','MPC','NBL','CXO','NOV','HES','MRO','EQT','XEC','FTI','RRC','OKE','SWN','NFX','HP','MUR','CHK','RIG','DO']
try:
   h13 = pd.HDFStore('port.h13')
   data = h13['norm']
   h13.close()
except:
   data = pd.DataFrame()
   for sym in symbols:
       data[sym] = web.DataReader(sym, data_source='yahoo', start='01/01/2016')['Adj Close']
   data = data.dropna()
   h13 = pd.HDFStore('port.h13')
   h13['norm'] = data
   h13.close()

(data / data.ix[0] * 100).plot(figsize=(8,6), grid = True)

log_returns = np.log(data / data.shift(1))
log_returns.hist(bins=50, figsize=(9,6))
lr = log_returns.iloc[1:]
sigma = np.cov(lr, rowvar = False)

lr_list = lr.T.values
myu_list=[sum(elem)/len(elem) for elem in zip(*lr_list.T)]  
std_list=[st.stdev(elem) for elem in zip(*lr_list.T)]  
lr_norm = (lr.as_matrix() - myu_list)/std_list
lr_cov = np.cov(lr_norm, rowvar = False, ddof = 0)
eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(lr_cov)
plt.plot(eig_vec[0:3].dot(lr_norm.T).T)
```

[image: PCs Plot]

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's about interpreting statistics, not programming.

Comment: It looks like youre taking the complex eigenvector, multiplying it by your covariance matrix and plotting the result. I'm not really sure of the interpretational value of that. I think what you'd actually want to do (maybe) is projecting all of your actual data onto the subspace of your eigenvector(s) and then plotting that to see where your data lies along each factor

Comment: @ Josh Caswell -- Thank you and noted. I'll be careful to post only technically relevant questions.

Comment: @ Simon -- Thank you! Indeed I think I'm already doing that via plt.plot(eig_vec[0:2].dot(lr_norm.T).T), where eig_vec are the eigen vectors and lr_norm is the original normalized (standardized) sample. I am definitely not multiplying the eig_vec with the covariance matrix (lr_cov). I guess I'll figure out next steps. Thanks again.